# custom login page for spring security oauth2 client login

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to implement social login in my spring boot 2 app with a custom login page. I place spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client as a dependency in my pom.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I then provide some client id and secret details in my application properties file..

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-id=client-id
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-secret=client-secret
```

With this minimal code spring boot registers the client and provides a login page with a link to login via the client. Now I want to provide my own login page so I have created a Seurity config..

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = false)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
          .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/auth/**", "/login/oauth2/**", "/login**", "/logout", "/**/*.css", "/**/*.js").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
          .oauth2Login().loginPage("/login")
            .and()
          .logout();   
    }   
}
```

I then provide a controller to serve up my custom login page, I have just put this in my spring boot config for now..

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
public class SingleSignonApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SingleSignonApplication.class, args);
    }
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String loginPage() {
        return "login.html";
    }
}
```

..and my login page (simplified) provides links to login via google..

```
<a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-google" href="/oauth2/authorization/google"><span class="fab fa-google"></span> Sign in with Google</a>
```

Now when I sign in via this button, it calls google, is authenticated and then when its redirected to login/oauth2/code/google... I get a 404 page not found. Also /logout stops working. Do I need to manually configure the other stuff as I realise I am relying on spring boot to continue setting up the clients listed in the app propertie file and set up a client repository automatically.

Comment: I got this to work by disabling csrf in my security config.. 
http.csrf().disable();
This got the logout working again and I think my other issue was caused by not logging out properly. Really struggling to find the most modern correct way to implement social log in. Does anyone know any good examples.

Comment: check here u will get....https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-5-oauth2-login

Comment: thanks @kumar this was helpful.

Comment: wrt /logout, note this from the documentation for LogoutConfigurer:
  The URL that triggers log out to occur (default is "/logout"). If CSRF protection
 is enabled (default), then the request must also be a POST. This means that by
 default POST "/logout" is required to trigger a log out. If CSRF protection is
 disabled, then any HTTP method is allowed.